# If you're short on time or came late to shul, which paragraphs of the selichot should you recite? (sefardic version)

Tags: tefilla, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, selichot, arriving-late

If you come late to shul and need to catch up while the congregation is finishing selihot or has already started shacharit, which paragraphs of the selichot should you recite? I would like answers for the sefardic version of the selichot.

Comment: Since Sfardi and Ashkenazi slichot are very different, i would expect them to have different rules.